# the string 'false' is not a valid boolean value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am reading a value that is being written as a string using XmlWriter.  Then it is being read by XmlReader and converted to a boolean.  Finally, the same XmlWriter method is called to write out to a separate Xml file. But when I try to write the element the second time I am getting a failed unit test that says:

```
Result Message: 
Test method threw exception: 
System.FormatException: The string 'False' is not a valid Boolean value.
```

I am writing the element with

```
   writer.WriteStartElement("variableNameIsRelative");
   writer.WriteCData(p.VariableNameIsRelative.ToString());
   writer.WriteEndElement();
```

then reading with

```
param.VariableNameIsRelative = XmlConvert.ToBoolean(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
```

and again using the same writer as before just outputting to a different file (this is where it breaks.)

```
writer.WriteStartElement("variableNameIsRelative");
writer.WriteCData(p.VariableNameIsRelative.ToString());
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

So my question is..Is there anything different I have to do to convert "false" to a valid boolean value in XmlSerialization vs what I am currently doing here? And if so, what might that be?

Comment: "the string false"? sounds like you built `<variableNameIsRelative><![CDATA[false]]></variableNameIsRelative>`. that's literally a string with the letters `f`, `a`, `l`, etc...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`XmlConvert.ToBoolean` only accept `false` in lower case string. You are probably confusing it with [`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

[XmlConvert.ToBoolean Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Valid strings are "1" or "true" for true and "0" or "false" for false.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Thank you!  I will mark as answer when Stack Overflow lets me.